# Complex Integrals, Two different methods provide different answers

Tags: complex-analysis

$$\int_{|z|=1/4} \frac{\sin(z)}{z^2}\, dz$$
If I do Cauchy there is a pole at $z = 0$, so the answer is $\sin(0)2\pi i = 0$. If I use series, I get $2\pi i$. Am I doing something wrong?

edit: its 1/4 not 5/4, it was a typo

$$\frac{\sin(z)}{z^2}\ = \frac{1}{z}\ + ... +,$$

Now the $$\frac{A}{z}\,$$ is what you want, A is one so it turns into $$2 \pi i$$

Comment: Most likely you _are_ doing something wrong. Can you show your calculation process?

Comment: Call $\sin z / z = g(z)$ where $g(0)=1$. Now, you can see that $g(z)/z(z+1)$ has a simple pole at $0$. Its residue is $g(0)/(0+1)=1$, not $0$.

Comment: if you use the Cauchy integral formula $\int \frac {f(z)}{z^2}\ dz = 2\pi i \frac {df}{dz} (0)$

Comment: I wasnt paying attention to what n is in the CIF. So I differentiate sin(z) and get the correct answer